# how to use two entity manager for one direction in symfony 4

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, entitymanager

I'm working with multiple Entity Managers, followed Symfony doc from [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html),
but I want to use two entity manager for one dir.
It's not working properly in findAll or findOneBy query, it's showing the result for 'default' entity manager.

in config/packages/doctrine.yaml :

```
dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4
            default_table_options:
                charset: utf8mb4
                collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

            url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'

        blog:
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            url: '%env(DATABASE_BLOG_URL)%'
            charset: utf8mb4
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            mappings:
                Main:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: Main

        blog:
            connection: blog
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            mappings:
                blog:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: blog
```

in controller:

```
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('blog');

    $University = $entityManager->getRepository(University::class)
            ->findOneBy(array('Code' => $Code));
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - what is a practical case for such design decision?

Comment: @Flying its a multi-language project, I used one source code with multi databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend inject the connection as a service in your Controller and leverage autowiring

//CONTROLLER

```
public function testController(YourService $service){
        return $service->test();
}
```

//services.yml

```
App\Service\YourService:
    public: true
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager','@doctrine.orm.blog']
```

//src/service/YourService.php

```
class YourService {
    private $blog,$em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em, EntityManager $blog) {
    $this->em = $em
    $this->blog = $blog;
}

 public function test()
    {
        //connect to blog
        $this->blog->getRepository(your_entity::class)->findAll();
        //connect to default
        $this->em->getRepository(your_entity::class)->findAll();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I`ve injected 'blog' entity manager to my Repository and it worked with createQueryBuilder!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put the name of your second DB in the second argument of the function getRepository, like this:

```
$University = $entityManager->getRepository(University::class, 'blog')
            ->findOneBy(array('Code' => $Code));
```

**Update 2:**

Use only this configuration, without specify dir, but by using this, you will obligate to use the vanilla SQL to intercate with your DB:
blog:
      connection: blog
      naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore

my last suggestion will be to create differente folders Entities for each connection, and duplicate in it the sames entities, and like this you can use the ORM DOCTRINE properly.

Comment: Yeah, I did, but I got the same result.